# Overwrite path already set in Background

Tags: karate

Is there a way to overwrite `path` after it's been set in `Background:`?

I have a lot of tests (boundary values) which are basically only varied by what function I test them on. So its nice that I can set `path` in `Background`.
But on the odd occasion, I need to chain several calls and therefore also the `path` variable.

If I do

```
Given path 'Client/GetClient'
...
Given path 'GetServices'
...
```

the path is being overwritten correctly on each `path` call, but if I do

```
Background:
  * path 'Client/GetClient'
...
Given path 'GetServices'
```

the `Given`path is being appended to the already defined `Background` path so that it becomes `Client/GetClient/GetServices`.
I want it to be `Client/GetClient` the first time, and `GetServices` the second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the "append" behavior is by design and it works well in typical testing of REST-ful URL-s ! But why don't you move the background path into your test ?

```
Given path basePath, 'Client', 'GetClient'
...
Given path basePath, 'GetServices'
```

(EDIT removed wrong info).

The other suggestion is don't use `path` and use only URL:

```
Given url myUrl + '/basePath/Client/GetClient'
...
Given url myUrl + '/basePath/GetServices'
```

Comment: I'm not finding much joy in calling `Given url` after its already been defined in `Background`, as a mechanism to reset `path`. The reasoning behind using `Background`, is to avoid possibly missing a manual path update when I copy the tests to other REST functions. I'll do without, when chaining calls.

Comment: @PebermynteLars oops my bad, `url` does not reset, edited my answer. I could add a new keyword to "overwrite" path, but this is hard to design and not worth it, so I think avoiding `Background` for path is best for now.

Comment: ...unless you have a dozen or so tests that all call the endpoint the same way, plus one or two that mutate the path to test invalid permutations. That means you end up declaring a variable and having to repeat `Given path` in those dozen tests just so the other two won't be broken, which isn't very DRY.

Comment: @TimKeating easily solved by not using the `Background` and using a data-driven `Scenario`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests P.S. DRY for tests is over-rated :P

Comment: I solved my particular problem by segregating just the scenarios that needed path manipulation into a separate feature, but I will have to revisit data-driven tests and see whether that can work for me. 

As for the other thing... if I didn't care about DRY for test automation, I wouldn't be looking at Karate as a potential replacement for Postman!

Comment: @TimKeating lol ok :) actually it just hit me we could add a ‘paths’ keyword that takes a json array - if it makes data-driven testing easier for this use case